# How do I get an iPhone app that works really well as is on the iPad listed for iPad on the iTunes store?

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes-store

From the Apple iOS App Store Review Guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

2.10 iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

My  app works perfectly when set up for iPhone on both iPhone and iPad.  If I set the app to universal or iPad as is, it has problems.  Is there a way to get it listed as an iPad app as is?  Or do I have to make up a separate iPad version?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the app for `ipad`, you need to make your app `Universal`. As you said if you set it for only `iphone` it works properly in both `ipad` and `iphone` but you will be seeing your `iphone` app in your `ipad`, its not an `ipad` app. The only issue you will be facing is, when you launch your app with only `iphone` version it will be only available in `iphone` appstore. If you try to search in `ipad` appstore you will not be able to see your app,unless you change the option to `iphone` only(after searching in appstore you will be seeing `ipad only` or `iphone only` options on top left corner of appstore).

> So if you want your app to be listed in `ipad` appstore then you need
>   to make it `Universal` there is no other option and you need make your
>   app compatible with `ipad`.

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Universal screws up the iPad version something awful while if it is put on the iPad as an iPhone app it works perfectly.  Anyway it only took me a few hours to set up the iPad version and get it submitted.